# Having Trouble with Split, Contains, and if

Tags: c#, split, contains

I wan to have the output to be `"WE ARE THE CHAMPIONS MY FRIEND"` as being *1 space* between each two words. So I do not want my code to continue if the any of the string contains a space in the array input2, but it just runs the if statement even if the item is white space. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

```cs
string input = "    WE ARE     THE    CHAMPIONS  MY  FRIEND";
string[] input2 = input.Split(' ');
string result = "";

foreach (var item in input2) {      
    if (!item.Contains(" "))
        result += item + " ";
}

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Between two consecutive spaces, you don't get a space but an empty string (which doesn't contain a space)

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1:**
One approach would be to use replace instead a combination of Split, Contains, and if as it is much simpler and less costly.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // This is the input string we are replacing parts from.
        string input = "    WE ARE     THE    CHAMPIONS  MY  FRIEND";

        // Use Regex.Replace to replace the pattern in the input.
        string output = Regex.Replace(input, "\\s+", " ");

        // Write the output.
        Console.WriteLine(input);
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

**Approach 2:**
To keep inline with your initial question of using Split, Contains, and if, the method Split takes in 3 parameters.

Parameters:

**separator:** It is a character array that delimits the substrings in this string, an empty array that contains no delimiters, or null.

**count:** It is the maximum number of substring to return.

**options:** RemoveEmptyEntries option to omit empty array elements from the array returned or None option to include empty array elements in the array returned.

```
public String[] Split(char[] separator, int count, StringSplitOptions options);
```

Hence after making the necessary changes, your final code becomes:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input="    WE ARE     THE    CHAMPIONS  MY  FRIEND";
        String[] spearator = {" "}; 
        String[] input2=input.Split(spearator, 1000, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
        String result="";

    foreach(var item in input2) {
            result+=item+" ";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But since I ve just started learning it, I am actually more interested in why the code runs the if statement more than the solution. It should not process the code in the if statement to my knowledge but it does. I guess I am missing something serious...

Comment: Try changing the if to if(item.Length > 1).

Comment: @dswdsyd the test should be `item.Length > 0`, else you would ignore single letter words ("*I* am *a* champion")

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers. It really helped a lot.